# React setState working then getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

New to React, creating an app for a Codecademy project which calls Spotify Web API.

The API call is working: I'm getting an access token and expiry timer, then getting song results returned in an array. I am then using `setState` in App.js so that `searchResults` = the array returned by Spotify. I am then passing `searchResults` from `state` through `props` to child components.

App.js (state) -> Search-container.js -> Search-view.js -> SearchResults-container.js -> SearchResults-view.js -> Track-container.js

I can see the `state` is getting successfully passed by the `props` because I am logging `this.props.searchResults` to the console in Track-container.js and seeing the results array.

However, on the next line in the console it is becoming `undefined`.

Screenshot of console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGmog.png

Console:

```
Did update
Track-container.js:19 [{…}]
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 undefined
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 [{…}]
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 undefined
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 [{…}]
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 undefined
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 [{…}]
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 undefined
Spotify.js:44 BQBLcVOKRR7i2MjOoNu9lp4He2oOJ1FN8e90Cbben-naezHF3DP7ZWgTlCcDvIBXsa5KXQndALtkoxBtY3RYR8BhTfVnZ5QdlE-vMVQ_mgnlHqT4M_6TpLYVEisn9kw_9slvh_nPhyRIGvg7gA
Spotify.js:45 3600
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Track-container.js:18 Did update
Track-container.js:19 undefined
```

The componentDidUpdate() method in Track-container.js is logging to the console every time I type in the search field (which has an onChange handler). Not sure if this is expected behavior in React?

My code:

**Spotify.js:**

```
export class Spotify extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getAccessToken() {
    if (userAccessToken) { // If access token already defined
      return userAccessToken;

    } else if (window.location.href.match(userAccessTokenRegex) != null) { // If access token is not yet defined but there is an access token in the URL

        // Set access token from URL hash fragment
        userAccessToken = window.location.href.match(userAccessTokenRegex)[1];
        // Set expiry timer from URL hash fragment
        expiresIn = window.location.href.match(expiresInRegex)[1];
        // Wipe the access token after expiry timer runs out
        window.setTimeout(() => userAccessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
        // Clear the parameters from the URL
        window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');

    } else {
        window.location = authUrl; // Redirect to Spotify auth
    }
  }

  async search(term) {
    if (userAccessToken === undefined) {
      this.getAccessToken();
      console.log(userAccessToken);
      console.log(expiresIn);
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=' + term, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`}
      })
      if (response.ok) {
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
        let tracks = jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
                id: track.id,
                name: track.name,
                artist: track.artists[0].name,
                album: track.album.name,
                uri: track.uri
            }));
        return tracks;
      }
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

};
```

**App.js:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      'term': '',
      "searchResults": [
        {}
      ]
    }

    // Create Spotify
    this.Spotify = new Spotify();

    // Bind this
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
  }

  // onChange handler for child input
  handleChange(e) {
    const term = e.target.value; // Take value from child component input field
    this.setState({ // Update state with value
      term: term
    });
  }

  // onSubmit handler for SearchBar input
  onSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.search(this.state.term);
  }

  // Search method
  async search(term) {
    const results = await this.Spotify.search(term);
    this.setState({
      searchResults: results
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="columns is-marginless">
        <main className="column is-two-thirds has-padding-40">
          <header>
            <h1 className="title">Jammming</h1>
            <h2 className="subtitle">Create Spotify playlists.</h2>
          </header>
          <Search searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onChange={this.handleChange} onSearch={this.onSearch} value={this.state.term} />
        </main>

        <aside className="column is-one-third is-paddingless">
          <Playlist />
        </aside>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*[...4 components in the middle each passing state down via props...]*

**Track-container.js:**

```
export class Track extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('Did update');
        console.log(this.props.searchResults);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Ultimately in Track-container.js I want to map the array to output a `<TrackView />` component for each item in the array, but I can't do that yet because the array is `undefined`.

*Edit:*

Adding the code for the search components in case the error is there.

**Search-container.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
// Import child components
import { SearchView } from './Search-view';

export class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SearchView searchResults={this.props.searchResults} onChange={this.props.onChange} onSearch={this.props.onSearch} value={this.props.value} />
    );
  }
}
```

**Search-view.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
// Import child components
import { SearchBar } from './SearchBar';
import { SearchResults } from './SearchResults';

export const SearchView = (props) => {
  return (
    <section className="Search">
      <SearchBar onChange={props.onChange} onSearch={props.onSearch} value={props.value} />
      <SearchResults searchResults={props.searchResults} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

**SearchBar-container.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { SearchBarView } from './SearchBar-view';
import Spotify from '../../../../utils/Spotify';

export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <SearchBarView onChange={this.props.onChange} onSearch={this.props.onSearch} value={this.props.value} />
      <h2>{this.props.value}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**SearchBar-view.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.scss'; // Import styles
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons';

export const SearchBarView = (props) => {
    return (
      <form className="SearchBar columns is-variable is-2" onSubmit={props.onSearch}>
        <div className="column">
          <p className="control has-icons-left">
            <input className="input is-large" placeholder="Enter a song, album, or artist" onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value} />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="column is-narrow">
          <button className="SearchButton button is-large is-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
}
```

**SearchResults-container.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
// Import components
import { SearchResultsView } from './SearchResults-view';

export class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SearchResultsView searchResults={this.props.searchResults} />
    );
  }
}
```

**SearchResults-view.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
// Import components
import { Track } from '../../Track';

export const SearchResultsView = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Track searchResults={props.searchResults} />
    </>
  );
}
```

GitHub repo: https://github.com/edxv/jammming

Comment: In Spotify.js after getting jsonResponse return jsonResponse.  And in app.js when initialising state try searchResults:[ ] and remove [{ }]. Now you should see expected output

Comment: What about SearchResults component?

Comment: Since this is a project you are doing as a tutorial, do you have it posted to github or anything? I think the component structure is good. Your Spotify API doesn't need to be a component, since you aren't using it like one. You use it like a regular class.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your post. That just creates more work for all of us.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is going on. Although there are some things that could be changed to be more idiomatic, the code is working.

You have Track two components. One is a child of the Search and the other is a child of the Playlist. The Track component in the Playlist does not take any props so searchResults is undefined. The Track in Search is fine, and has an array of tracks.

It is your console.log that is misleading you. Those two componentDidUpdate calls are from two distinct nodes in the tree.

Keep working on the tutorial. React Dev Tools shows you what props are on each component and your Search Track definitely has the array.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @edx it works fine for me. May be you try this once again and let me know. In SPotify.js :

```
async search(term) {
    if (userAccessToken === undefined) {
      this.getAccessToken();
      console.log(userAccessToken);
      console.log(expiresIn);
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=' + term, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`}
      })
      if (response.ok) {
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
       return jsonResponse.tracks.items;
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

In App.js :

```
this.state = {
   searchResults : []
}
```

In Track-container : 
i tried in return :

{this.props.searchResults && this.props.searchResults.map( item => {item.album.name})}

Comment: It is because When the component renders the results is undefined. It doesn’t have the value. So you need to protect the code. If you use immutable or loadash it will take care of this. Glad it worked